# What's a suitable CC-EDICT definition for 各司其职?

Tags: chengyu, meaning

I encountered 各司其职 in my textbook 发展汉语，高级口语（I） on page 19, so I'm attempting to whip up a CC-EDICT definition.

**Question**: What's a suitable CC-EDICT definition for 各司其职?

The definition the textbook gives is:

> 每个人尽自己的职责，做好所承担的工作。

This translates to something like:

> Everyone to the extent of their duty, performs well all undertaken work.

Based on this, my teacher's verbal descriptions, and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%90%84%E5%8F%B8%E5%85%B6%E8%81%B7#Chinese) and [Baidu Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%90%84%E5%8F%B8%E5%85%B6%E8%81%8C/258443?fr=aladdin), this is my attempt at a [CC-EDICT](https://cc-cedict.org/editor/editor.php) definition:

```
各司其職 各司其职 [ge4 si1 qi2 zhi2] /each performs their own function or duty/
```

I'm hoping for a for a critique and improvements on this.

I'm not sure if "function" is a good choice here (but it's what Baidu Baike uses).  I'm also unsure of this is just limited to humans, but could also refer to e.g. machinery (with each component performing its role).

---

CC-EDICT definitions and need to be high-quality (they're used in dictionaries all over the world).  The whole dictionary is free to download.  Submissions are [reviewed](https://cc-cedict.org/editor/editor.php?handler=ListChanges) prior to modifying the database.  They have a [specific syntax](https://cc-cedict.org/editor/editor.php?popup=1&handler=ContributorManual), e.g.:

> ```
> 中國 中国 [Zhong1 guo2] /China/Middle Kingdom/
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In Modern Chinese Dictionary 7ed (《现代汉语词典》第七版）

> 各司其职【gèsī-qízhí】
>
> 各自管好、做好自己的本职工作（司：执掌，主管）。
>
> 也说各尽其职、各司其事。

---

I would put it as

> 各司其職 各司其职 [ge4 si1 qi2 zhi2] /manages and performs one's own job respectively/

---

Hope my answer helps.